# How to access internal datas of Quarkus ClientWebApplicationException

Tags: java, exception, quarkus

I am quite new in Java world, so may be my question does not make too much sense...
Currently I am developing small application which uses the Quarkus Rest client (using @RegisterRestClient and so on..). One of the things that I am trying to achieve is to handle also the http errors (4xx, 5xx). These appear as exceptions, that I can catch. For instance the **ClientWebApplicationException** is thrown when a 400 error is received. When I use the debugger I see that the exception contains a lot of valuable information. Here is a small snapshot of what I see:

```
 - detailMessage: "Received bad request, status code 400..."
 - response:
   - restClientRequestContext:
     - httpClient:...
     - httpMethod = "POST"
     - uri = http://localhost:8080/...
     - ...
     - requestHeaders:
       - headers:
```

In my case I will have more rest clients, I plan to have an exception mapper. I want to be able, inside the exception mapper, to be able to distinguish which exception from which client comes, what was the request that had the http error reply and so on...
So when I saw the content of the exception, I was quite happy because all kind of contextual data is displayed by the debugger. However I am not able to access this data programmatically. The interface of the **ClientWebApplicationException** has a `getResponse()` but the returned response object does not propose anything like `getResponse().restClientRequestContext().getrequestHeaders() ...`

So I am not sure, if what I am trying to achieve is possible or may be it is possible but for now I cannot find the right way to do the things.

Is there someone that can provide me with some guidance ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use @ClientExceptionMapper [doc here](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-reactive#using-clientexceptionmapper) to manage the Response object that give you some accessors

Comment: I read here and there, it could be smth related to injecting of context (@Context or @Inject) of smth called HttpServletRequest/HttpRequest.
But as I said, I am completely new with Java (Quarkus).
I can't understand what I need to put in my pom.xml as dependency and then to use it where I need.
I see a lot of examples talking about importing javax. but never importing jakarata. concerning the HttpServletRequest/HttpRequest. 
I saw that in Quarkus there is something called Undertow  but still I am reading about it and not sure if it will do the work.